# When do we reject a null hypothesis by looking at both P variable of f statistic and F statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-regression, p-value, f-statistic

In which cases do we reject the null hypothesis ?

Comment: 1. Why does the first instance of "f statistic" have f in lower case and the second instance have upper case? What distinction are you drawing in your title? 2. There'd be little point in using both to decide whether you reject since the conclusion would be the same. You use one or the other and make a decision based on that

Comment: will you present your results/ output ?

Answer (score 1):

You reject the null when the p is below the amount you have decided on.

You can do the same thing via F, but it's trickier becuase F has different critical values for each numerator and denominator degree of freedom.

However, I'd be very leery of doing anything based solely on *either* p values or F values. Good decisions require thought and substantive knowledge.